# Why Each degree of freedom, (i.e. motion in $x$, $y$ or $z$) has $\frac{1}{2} k_B T$ worth of energy associated with its random motion?

Tags: energy, statistical-mechanics, ideal-gas

I am trying to interpret the result of
$\frac{3}{2}k_BT=\frac{1}{2}m\langle v^2\rangle$

I understand that temperature is equal to the average kinetic energy associated with particle motion.

$T=\frac{1}{k_B}\frac{1}{3}m\langle v^2\rangle$ where $\frac{\langle v^2\rangle}{3}$ is the  velocity of each particle but I don't get why $\frac{1}{2} k_B T$ is the worth of energy associated with its random motion?

Comment: [Three proofs here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equipartition_theorem#Derivations) of the equipartition theorem (the third will be the least useful for you).

Answer (score 3):

The equipartition theorem is a great tool to understand this. It stems from around that for every degree of freedom that appears to have a quadratic contribution to the total energy has such a form as you stated.
This is a generalisation which can be be placed into for a general power of 2 or more to the total energy instead. Which would give a contribution $$\frac{1}{s}k_BT $$
(For any s greater than or equal to 2.) Which mainly is in regards to the Anharmonic oscillator's average potential energy

There are many interesting resources on this, the wiki article on this theorem is particularly useful